# Yii2: display some records at the top of GridView widget

Tags: php, yii, yii2

In Yii2 app I have model `Document` which can belong to user. Belonging is set with `owner_id` field.
In view I display list of Documents using `GridView` widget. Default sort is by `document_id`.

Every user sees all documents (event if specific document doesn't belong to him).

But I need to display documents which belongs to current logged in user at the top of `GridView`. How can I do this?

I suppose I should make some changes to `Document::search()` method by can't find out what excactly I should do.

Here is my controller action:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $modelFullName = $this->modelFullName;

    $model = new $modelFullName();
    $dataProvider = $model->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    return $this->render(
        'index',
        [
            'model' => $model,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]
    );
}
```

Part of view:

```
echo GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel'  => $model,
    'columns' => [
        [
            'attribute' => 'document_id',
        ],
        [
            'attribute' => 'status',
            'format' => 'raw',
            'value' => function($model) {
                return $model->statusString;
            },
        ],
        [
            'attribute' => 'title',
        ],
        [
            'attribute' => 'date_created'
        ],
        [
            'attribute' => 'client_id',
            'value' => function($model) {
                return $model->client ? $model->client->title : '';
            },
            'filter' => ArrayHelper::map(Clients::find()->all(), 'client_id', 'title')
        ],
        [
            'attribute' => 'project_id',
            'value' => function($model) {
                return $model->project ? $model->project->title : '';
            },
            'filter' => ArrayHelper::map(Projects::find()->all(), 'project_id', 'title')
        ],
        [
            'class' => yii\grid\ActionColumn::className(),
            'template' => '{view} {delete}',
            'buttons' => [
                'view' => function ($url, $model) {
                    return $this->context->getBtn('view', $model);
                },
                'delete' => function ($url, $model) {
                    if (Yii::$app->user->can('deletePrsSum')) {
                        return $this->context->getBtn('delete', $model);
                    }
                },
            ],
            'visibleButtons' => [
                'update' => Yii::$app->user->can('updateDocument'),
                'delete' => Yii::$app->user->can('deleteDocument'),
            ]
        ],
    ],
]);
```

Current Document::search() implementation:

```
public function search($params)
{
    $query = self::find();

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
        'sort' => [
            'defaultOrder' => ['document_id' => SORT_ASC]
        ]
    ]);

    $this->load($params);

    if (!$this->validate()) {
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    if ($this->client_id) {
        $query->andFilterWhere([
            'client_id' => $this->client_id,
        ]);
    }

    if ($this->project_id) {
        $query->andFilterWhere([
            'project_id' => $this->project_id,
        ]);
    }

    return $dataProvider;
}
```

---

**UPDATE**
So how I managed to do this:

```
public function search($params)
    {
        $userId = Yii::$app->user->identity->user_id;
        $query = self::find()->select(
            "*, IF(owner_id={$userId},(0),(1)) as sort_order"
        )->orderBy([
            'sort_order' => SORT_ASC,
            'document_id' => SORT_ASC
        ]);
        //further code...
```

Comment: Post your controller action, grid view and, if you have a SearchModel, post it here. Or your model code.

Comment: I think you have to write a custom $query object that contains an UNION with a SELECT filtered by user documents and a second SELECT filtered by all other documents.

Comment: @omerowitz ready

Comment: Please check my answer below.

Comment: @FabrizioCaldarelli thank you! that's what I realy needed!

Answer (score 0):

Add a filter in your search function to filter with the id of the logged in person/user:
 `$query->andFilterWhere(['owner_id' => Yii::$app->user->identity->id]);`